# Improve performance when creating a new column using another column as a lookup table

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a main dataframe with 4 columns representing 4 colors and 3 rows representing 3 types of materials. The values in this frame are either 1 or 0, where 1's indicate POSITIVE, and 0 NEGATIVE.
I have another very long dataframe with multiple columns, including a column for COLOR and another column for MATERIAL. For each row in this frame, the values will be different. The main table indicates which combination of COLOR and MATERIAL is considered POSITIVE. Now, I want to create a new column in this frame called 'FAVOR', such that for a combination of color and material indicated as POSITIVE (with value 1) in the main table,if the same combination occurs in this long dataframe, the value should be `1`, else `0`.

I did something along the lines of :

```
for i in pairs:
    main_frame['FAVOR'].loc[(main_frame['Color']==i[0]) & (main_frame['Material']==i[1])]='1'
```

where `pairs` is a list I created using the main table, in which each item is a pair of MATERIAL and COLOR for which the value is 1.

The above lines of code ran for over 30 mins and I ran out of patience. 
I understand that a row-wise operation like this is typically inefficient in Pandas. But is there any faster way to achieve what I am trying to do?

EDIT:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

main_frame = pd.DataFrame({'Color':['g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's', 'f', 'o', 
             'r', 'g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's'],'Material':['p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'm', 
                        'm', 'i', 'n', 'g','k','n']})
lookup_table = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1, 0], 56).reshape(7,8),index=['g', 'e', 'k', 's', 'f', 'o', 'r'],columns=['p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'a', 'm','i', 'n'])
# n = np.random.choice([1, 0], 9).reshape(3,3)
print main_frame
print lookup_table
rows=[]
for i in lookup_table.index:
    rows.append(i)
cols=[]
for j in lookup_table.columns:
    cols.append(j)
pairs=[]
for i in rows:
    for j in cols:
        if lookup_table.loc[i,j]==1:
            pairs.append([i,j])
for i in pairs:
        main_frame['FAVOR'].loc[(main_frame['Color']==i[0]) & (main_frame['Material']==i[1])]='1'
```

This works for this sample code very quickly, but for my dataset with 1,000,000 records, this code takes significantly large amount of time.

Comment: Can you please provide a representative sample of your input data frames (preferably as run-able code), and an example of desired output.

Comment: @smj, I updated the question with the sample code to demonstrate what I am trying to do. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: so just to be clear, the output from the code above is as desired, and the help required is to achieve the same result faster?

Comment: @smj, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` after using `stack` and `reset_index` on `lookup_table`. First create df_stack:

```
df_stack = (lookup_table.stack().reset_index()
             .rename(columns={'level_0':'Color','level_1':'Material',0:'FAVOR'}))
print (df_stack.head(15))
   Color Material  FAVOR
0      g        p      0
1      g        r      0
2      g        o      1
3      g        g      1
4      g        a      1
5      g        m      0
6      g        i      0
7      g        n      1
8      e        p      0
9      e        r      0
10     e        o      0
11     e        g      0
12     e        a      0
13     e        m      0
14     e        i      0
```

you can see on a row, you have 0 or 1 associated to a couple (row, column) of your `lookup_table`, respectively in column I named Color and Material for the `merge`:

```
main_frame = main_frame.merge(df_stack, how='left').fillna(0)
```

the result in `main_frame` is with my random 0 and 1:

```
   Color Material  FAVOR
0      g        p    0.0
1      e        r    0.0
2      e        o    0.0
3      k        g    0.0
4      s        r    1.0
5      f        a    0.0
6      o        m    1.0
7      r        m    1.0
8      g        i    0.0
9      e        n    0.0
10     e        g    0.0
11     k        k    0.0
12     s        n    0.0
```

it should be faster than your method on a large df